# Plotly go Pie chart: change legend to show another column

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using `plotly.graph_objects` to make a pie chart of some data. (I'm having to use `.go` instead of `plotly.express` because I want the direction of the pie slices to display clockwise, something I couldn't find a way to control in `.px`.)

The slices are calculated by the `count` column and labels are in `Name`, but I want the legend to show the information in the `Access` column. Color coding means something in this case, and I want to display that information in the legend.

**Is there a way to configure and change the column that the legend shows?** I've looked at the detailed documentation
[Plotly.go Pie objects](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Pie.html) and the [Fundamentals: Legends with graph objects](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#legends-with-graph-objects) pages, but can't get it to work. The only way I've found is to change the `Pie.labels` itself to `Access`, but that of course changes the shape of the pie slices.

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

test = {'Name': ['Company A','Company B','Company C','Company D','Company E'], 'count': [11,40,18,32,5], 'color':['red','blue','green','red','green'], 'Access':['Closed','Half','Free','Closed','Free']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
df
```

[image: dataframe with columns Name, count, color, Access]

```
go_fig=go.Figure()
go_fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=df['Name'], values=df['count'], marker=dict(colors=df['color']), sort=False, direction='clockwise', textinfo='label+value+percent'))
go_fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two traces, just like overlapping two layers.
The new trace would fall on the top but turn the new legend off so it can reveal the old legend underneath.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=df['Access'], values=df['count'], marker_colors=df['color']))
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=df['Name'], values=df['count'], marker_colors=df['color'], showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be also useful to know that you can't change the legend, but you can customize the text displayed on the Pie chart by setting the **text** property and displaying it by using **textinfo**:

> Sets text elements associated with each sector. If trace textinfo contains a “text” flag, these elements will be seen on the chart...

```
go_fig=go.Figure()
go_fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=df['Access'], values=df['count'], text=df["Name"], textinfo='text+value+percent', marker=dict(colors=df['color']), sort=False, direction='clockwise'))
```

[image]

[More in the docs](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Pie.html)